# My cat has this wound on his forehead, does it look infected?

Tags: cats

My cat has had this scratch/wound for about a week , it scabs over but the next time i look at it , the scab is scratched off (as seen in the photo).

He doesn't seem to be in any pain and is feeding regularly.

I don't know what to do, please help! [image]

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture if it is infected, but if she keeps scratching there is a high risk of infection so she will need to wear a cone. I'd suggest to visit the vet, they can prescribe antibiotics to treat or prevent infection. The wound itself looks nasty enough to warrant a visit anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that **I'm not a vet**. In my personal opinion, this doesn't look infected. It looks quite usual for a superficial head wound in a cat.

Unfortunately, cats have a tendency to scratch scabs off their wounds (at least in my experience), which opens the wound up again and again and prolongs healing. My own cat did that for 5 months after a bad case of ear mites. Having the cat wear a cone can help the wound heal much faster, but it will still take several weeks to heal completely. You can apply a wound cream or natural oil to the scabs to moisturize it. Please keep in mind that **any cream or oil you apply must be non-toxic to cats**. Just because something is non-toxic to humans doesn't mean it's non-toxic to cats as well.

You should try to find the reason for the wound. Did he get it in a fight with another cat? (It doesn't look like it.) Did he try to squeeze through a hole that was too small? Or does he have an infection or something else in his nose or forehead that caused him to scratch that area? (That's exactly what happened to my cat with the ear mites.) You may need to see a vet to treat the underlying cause.

Answer (score 1):

The wound does not look infected but you should keep an eye on it,if it does not start to heal soon or changes color and starts to look infected you need to talk to your vet.

The important thing here is for your cat to leave the wound alone so it can heal on its own,you might need to get a cone to put on your cat if the wound don`t start to heal whitin a week.

A tiny scratch like that does not need any extra care or treatment it will heal on its own if your cat manages to leave it alone and if not you will need to put on a cone.

Answer (score 1):

Not a vet, but experienced with injured animals. The important thing here is just to prevent infection.

The best thing to do here is disinfect daily with something like Betadine. Get a bottle of 5% Betadine liquid and a pack of cotton wool from a pharmacy (don't need a prescription). Take out a bit of the liquid and dip some cotton wool in it and gently wipe the surface of the wound with it. It will burn a bit, so be sure to hold the cat properly.